# zend doctrine2 notice ObjectHydrator

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Got models with relations. When use getResult() method:

```
        $result = $queryBuilderProducts
        ->select('pr')
        ->from(Product::class, "pr")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: productProperties in ...doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\ObjectHydrator.php on line 122

Product.php:

```
/**
 * @var \Showcases\Entity\ProductProperty[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Showcases\Entity\ProductProperty", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $productProperties;
```

ProductProperties.php:

```
/**
 * @var \Showcases\Entity\Product
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Showcases\Entity\Product", inversedBy="productProperties", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $product;
```

Comment: targetEntity="\Showcases\Entity\ProductProperty", targetEntity="\Showcases\Entity\Product ?

Comment: It did not help